# REST method calling D2l For an enrollment but returns status 303

Tags: rest, desire2learn, http-status-code-303

I'm trying to enroll a user with a REST method. The user exists, and I'm using as endpoint `/d2l/api/lp/1.0/enrollments/`

The params and sign params are right, because I was able to create the user, and perform other calls.

But the only response I'm getting for that call is

```
[Status=See other, StatusCode=303]
```

And nothing else, like the URL to redirect.

Has somebody been through this already? Or any hints of what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the rights to enroll are granted based on a matrix of permissions (RoleType,OrgUnitType). That is, your calling user may be able to create a user record and enroll that user as a Student Role in the Organization org unit type, and *not* have the permissions to enroll that user in a Department, Semester, Course Offering, or other org unit type.

The 303 you're getting is most likely a redirect to an error page as a result of your POST failing for some reason. If you're able to make other calls fine, then the most likely errors are that your calling user context is not permitted to make the enrollment action you're trying, you're not identifying the user, user role, or org unit properly in the `CreateEnrollmentData` block you're passing, or the block is malformed in some way.

It may help to further diagnose the issue if you use Fiddler, WireShark, or some other packet sniffer utility to closely examine the exact HTTP request you're making, and the exact response traffic you're getting back as a result. For more assistance there, you can look at this [blog article on D2L's Developer Blog](https://community.brightspace.com/devcop/blog/troubleshooting_your_web_applications_using_a_network_trace~1).

Comment: I am having a similar problem and would like to see the article, but the link you provided is broken.  Do you have an updated link?

Comment: Link has been updated -- D2L's developer blog topics moved into D2L's Developer Community site.